# How to draw a MongoDB diagram

Tags: mongodb, diagram, database

I am recently working on a django project documentation which uses MongoDB.
So I need to know how to make some clear diagrams of the MongoDB collections.

I understand that there's no fixed form to do it due to the MongoDB's flexible nature,
 but my records in each collection follows certain order and rule defined by the collection while some of the collection records contain inner documents.

So, is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXvC8.png) the most proper way, or there's more standard way to show my MongoDB collections to other developers or package users?

Comment: That makes sense. But if the users are technical, I would provide them JSON too, as that is what they would be looking at most of the time

Comment: @java_dude Thanks. going hierarchical JSON (fields and descriptions)should do.

Comment: An UML database model would be the best and most lasting approach: it is easy, DBMS independent and every developer should be able to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugguest the tree mode.

```
collection
`-- _id
`-- field1
`-- field2
    `-- f1
    `-- f2
`-- field3
```